# Combining loop_start(), loop_stop(), and loop_forever(); launching the separate application

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Is it correct to use `client.loop_start()`, do some things, then `client.loop_stop()`, and finally `client.loop_forever()`?

**Context:** I have a `bootloader.py` on my Raspberry device. The bootloader is to be launched automatically when the device boots. The bootloaders connects to the application server (via dedicated IP and topic), checks the expected sofware installed at the device, downloads the newer software if it is not available locally, starts the wanted application, and then the bootloader should become a subscriber that listens to the "service messages" from outside. (For example: "send me your status", "check for the new software, and if there is something new, download it and reboot the device".

**Current implementation:** I have already implemented the loading process and launching the wanted application. The implementation uses the `client.loop_start()` (that is processing the communication using separathe thread). After downloading the wanted files, the bootloader calls `subprocess.Popen(cmd)`, and becomes the proces of the launched application.

**What I want:** Now I want to separate the process of the launched application. The bootloader should became a client that listens *forever*. My idea was to `client.loops_stop()` after the communication with the application server was finished, launch the application, and then `client.loop_forever()` as the last action of the script to make it listening forever. Is such approach correct?

Is the described situation usual? Is it a well known pattern? If yes, could you point me to the related documentation? If no, can you see any flaw in the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a pattern I've seen elsewhere, but if it meets your needs.

The only problem would be if the time between calling `loop_stop()` and `loop_forever()` is longer than the Keep Alive period which will result in the broker disconnecting the client.

You may also get a burst of messages when you restart the event loop.

Comment: Thanks hardillb. Can you comment the Python paho mqtt implementation? (Probably only the interface to the C++ library.) As the loop_start() creates new thread, does the loop_stop() block until the thread is stopped. If the loop_forever() is then called immediately, I guess it creates new thread. Could I consider the "burst of messages" rather minimal in such case? Actually, my goal is to make the bootloader process alive to serve the "service-like actions". Would you recommend another approach?

Comment: `loop_forever()` does not start a new thread, it runs (and blocks) the current thread that calls the function. Since you tagged the question as python, all comments are with regards to the paho python library